# Using numpy to compute the squared sum of distances between values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am a newbie in python and stackoverflow. I am trying to change my way of thinking about loops.
I have a series of values which type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.

**Goal:** Giving a depth n, I would like to compute for each value (except the first 2*n-2) :

```
result(i) = sum[j=0 to n-1](distance(i-j)*value[i-j])/sum[j=0 to n-1](distance[j])

with distance(i) = sum[k=1 to n-1]((value[i]-value[i-k])^2)
```

I want to avoid loops, so is there a better way to achieve my goal using numpy?

EDIT :
Ok, it seems that I am not that clear so here is an example with n= 4 :

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 7 |

Then I compute the squared difference (value[i]-value[j])^2 with j=i-1 to i-3 :

| diff² | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  | 9 | 16 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  | 9 | 25 | 49 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  | 36 | 64 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | 9 | 16 | 25 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |  | 36 | 49 | 4 |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 64 | 9 | 1 |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 9 | 25 | 36 |  |

I think that getting this matrix, full or not is the core of my problem.
I can now compute distance(i) which is the sum of a row and distance(i)*value(i) :

| Index | distance | distance x Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 6 | 18 |
| 4 | 29 | 29 |
| 5 | 83 | 664 |
| 6 | 101 | 909 |
| 7 | 50 | 200 |
| 8 | 89 | 178 |
| 9 | 74 | 74 |
| 10 | 70 | 490 |

And finally I can get the result :

| Index | Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 5 |  |
| 3 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 8 |  |
| 6 | 9 | 7.397260274 |
| 7 | 4 | 6.851711027 |
| 8 | 2 | 6.040247678 |
| 9 | 1 | 4.334394904 |
| 10 | 7 | 3.328621908 |

For example :

```
result(10) = (distance(10)*value(10)+distance(9)*value(9)+distance(8)*value(8)+distance(7)*value(7))/(distance(10)+distance(9)+distance(8)+distance(7))
```

I have a Java version of the algorithm if needed.
Thank you.

UPDATE :
I finally found how to get the full sqared differences matrix :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n=4
myseries=pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1, 7])
l=len(myseries)

vector = np.repeat(myseries, l)
mat = vector.to_numpy().reshape((l, l))
diff = mat-np.transpose(mat)

squared_diff = np.multiply(diff, diff)

print(squared_diff)
```

I still have to get the sum of selected elements

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us some example input and expected output. Even adding your for-loop approach would be useful for comparing with

Comment: I added some explanation and expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

`myseries = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100), dtype='float32')`

`sum_of_squared_distances= np.sum(np.square(np.diff(myseries.values[:n][1::2])))`

where "n" is the nth index(depth) and [1::2] part gets only odd-index values since you only need values corresponding to odd-index(except 2*n-2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I need the differences between index i and index i-j with j between 1 and n-1 and not only odd ones.